# Font acts wierd on Windows PC but not on Mac/iPad

Tags: css, fonts

I use a custom font on my webpage using `@font-face { font-family: MyFont; src: url('myfont.otf'); }` and I have found a wierd thing about it, I'll try to explain it.

On a Mac/iPad: the height of the font is exactly the height of the letters.

On a Windows PC: the height of the font is exactly the height of the letters - BUT there is some kind of "padding" on top of the letters so that the bottom parts of letters like g, y, j, etc is outside of the font height. If I were to put a div right under the text, the g or y would "hang" inside of it.

There is no padding or margin involved and this is only shown on a Windows PC. On the Apple products it looks alright. How come!? It doesn't matter which browser I use. Is it fixable or do I have to find another font?

Hope that was clear, don't really know ho to explain it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTF fonts can be problematic in Windows sometimes. You're best specifying more than one font file so the client browser can pick the one it wants.

You can use a font-face generator such as: [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

You'll end up with something like this in your stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('MyFont.eot');
    src: url('MyFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('MyFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('MyFont.svg#MyFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it! :D